# Error establishing a database connection wordpress website

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I created a website with Wordpress.

My problem is that time by time appears an error that gives this message `Error establishing a database connection`.

I can fix this error when I login to the server and type this command: `sudo service mysql restart`.

I want to know if someone have an idea why this is happening?

Edit ----
Here is the result that i get after i run this command `df -h` :

[image: Server space]

Results after htop command : 
[image]

Comment: Sounds like your server isn't high performance enough to handle all of the requests your site is making to the database...

Comment: @mevius Actually this project is in first phase of development, so number of requests is really low?

Answer (score 1):

SSH into your server and run the following:

This will tell you how much free space you have in memory and disk.

```
df -h
```

I've found that if I run out of disk my server reboots. You might also find that your server provider has had an outage, which is more common then you'd realise.

To increase swap disk space (temporary ram), follow this tutorial:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-swap-on-ubuntu-14-04

If you want to automatically launch the mysql process on boot you can follow this guide:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-a-linux-service-to-start-automatically-after-a-crash-or-reboot-part-1-practical-examples

It depends on your operating system as to how you relaunch the service. It differs on Ubuntu.

--

**Edit**
It looks like you have enough disk space on the machine to operate normally.

You can check the amount of ram free by using this command:

```
htop
```

**Edit2**
Looks like you also have enough ram. The server has been up for 32 days however. I would recommend checking out how to restart your mysql instance when the server restarts and then reboot the server to check if your database comes back online.

Comment: Please check I added the result when i run that command. I'm using ubuntu.

Comment: No problem, let me know how you get on :)